# Bash скрипт который будет подставлять дату и данные из группы элементов

Tags: bash, скрипт, sh

Помогите пожалуйста начинающему студенту автоматизировать пожалуйста приемку отправку данных каталогов. 
Есть на сервере два файла один с конфигурацией **(upload.customizes)** для скрипта и сам скрипт **(./upload)**. 
 файле **upload.customizes** есть строка export DIR_REMOTE=/incoming/files-{date}/{group} , *date* и *group* переменные, нужно подставлять сегодняшнее число и вместо {group} элементы из массива " groups = {Klienty Baza Raschet Zarplata Nalogi}" - для примера Klienty. 
После чего сохранять файл и запускать скрипт 
sh ./upload который будет ожидать вывода- exiting fine.

после чего снова будет открываться **upload.customizes** и теперь в строчке export DIR_REMOTE=/incoming/files-20200204/Klienty вместо этого будет
Baza { DIR_REMOTE=/incoming/files-20200204/BAZA } и снова запускаться скрипт который будет ждать exiting fine.

я начал писать это дело и понял что все совсем плохо:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
groups = {Klienty Baza Raschet Zarplata Nalogi}
sed "s/{date}/$date/g" /home/appsupp/bin/sftp2db.customizes
sed "s/{group}/$groups/g" /home/appsupp/bin/sftp2db.customizes
```

можете пожалуйста помочь с подсказками хотя бы как подставлять данные из перечня переменных в groups? Спасибо всем громадное

Answer (score 2):

Очень советую : 
https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/x4462.html

Стоит прочитать и осмыслить, таких вопросов не возникнет.

Comment: Спасибо Андрей, вы чудесный человек! Дай вам Бог Здоровья

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле я не понял чего вы добиваетесь, но вот примерная схема для описанных вами действий, поставил комментарии к строкам

```bsh
#Объявляем переменную с датой
Now_date=`date +%Y%m%d`
#Объявляем массив с группами
groups=( "Klienty" "Baza" "Raschet" "Zarplata" "Nalogi" )
#Запускаем цикл по группам
for group in ${groups[@]}; do
#Объявляем переменную строки параметра
    DIR_REMOTE="/incoming/files-${Now_date}/${group}"
#Заменяем в файле конфига строку, для sed используем разделителем пайпт, так как слеш используется в путях
    sed -i "/DIR_REMOTE/s|.*|export DIR_REMOTE='${DIR_REMOTE}'|g;" /home/appsupp/bin/sftp2db.customizes
#Запускаем скрипт, не совсем понятно, для чего делать отдельный скрипт, но пусть
#Ловим экзепшн выхода из скрипта, если выполнение успешно и $? будет равно нулю, то сработает все хорошо
#Иначе вернет все плохо и прекратим выполнение цикла, но не скрипта, там уже exit можно будет поставить к примеру
    ./upload && { echo "Все хорошо"; continue; } || { echo "Все плохо"; break; }
#Завершение цикла
done
```

Comment: если есть пейпел кошелек оставьте пожалуйста в личку slava.zack@gmail.com спасибо вам

Comment: Вот как я доделал ваши наработки : спасибо вам https://privatebin.net/?e2fd4fa3b423ba71#2EvTHxwBLrh6qPSwnzK9g7X4qy2DSVMJcmhjocsVtxqV

Comment: Рад что информация пригодилась